# Deleting an object property with a function

Tags: javascript

Hey everyone İ am trying to write a function that accepts property name as an argument and deletes it. But i want a do it dynamically so i can change it anytime i want with other properties but i cant seem to make it. Help is much appreciated.

```js
const student = {
  names: "David Rayy",
  sclass: "VI",
  rollno: 12,

  deleteProperty(property) {
    console.log(property)
    delete property
    console.log(student)
  },
}

student.deleteProperty(this.rollno)
```

Comment: Why going on the hard way just use `delete student.rollno;`. Simple

Comment: `i am trying to write a function that accepts property name as an argument` if you want to have a function that accepts a property name as argument, then why do you pass `this.rollno` which is not a property name but a function?

Answer (score 2):

like that ?

```js
const student =
  { names  : 'David Rayy'
  , sclass : 'VI'
  , rollno : 12
  , deleteProperty(property) 
    {
    console.log('delete ->', property)
    delete this[property]
    console.log(this)
  }
}

student.deleteProperty('rollno')
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be passing in a *string* as an argument to the function so that it can be used as the property name.

```js
const student = {

  name: 'David Rayy',
  sclass: 'VI',
  rollno: 12,

  deleteProperty(property) {
    delete this[property];
  }

}

student.deleteProperty('rollno');

console.log(`
  Name: ${student.name},
  Class: ${student.sclass},
  Rollno: ${student.rollno}
`);
```

Modern JS veers towards using [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). So an *alternative solution* might be to create a Student class that accepts some arguments, and has a `deleteProperty` method. Then create a new student instance with that data, and then you can delete the property you want.

```js
class Student {

  constructor(name, sClass, rollNo) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sClass = sClass;
    this.rollNo = rollNo;
  }

  deleteProperty(property) {
    delete this[property];
    return this;
  }

  print() {
    console.log(this);
  }

}

const student = new Student('David', 'VI', 12);

student.print();
student.deleteProperty('rollNo').print();
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with using classes or not.

Comment: @Bergi I was just offering a different solution to the problem.

Comment: Still, your explanation sounds like one would *need* to use a class and create an instance of it to be able to delete the property. At no point the answer explains what the problem in the OP's code was.

Comment: TBF, the upvoted answer doesn't _explain_ what the problem was either. You're coming across as needlessly picky at this point.